# error when accessing colored item in terminal showed by "ls"

Tags: 18.04, bash

Good day, I am fairly new to linux and I wanted to get to the directory shown in my terminal after executing `ls`. Now when i tried `cd /foldername/` it gives an error `bash: cd:/foldername: No such file or directory` when it literally is there.

[Here](https://ibb.co/Rg41Kzj) is the actual sample pic for reference of the error I'm getting.
Any help and suggestions are much appreciated, thank you!.

Comment: Your operating system is correct; `/powerdnsadmin` does not exist. Just type `cd powerdnsadmin` if you are already in the parent directory. Having a slash in front means it’s a top-level directory 

Comment: @Matigo oh. I didn't think it would make such difference. Thank you sir!